# BS4 LoveCalculator doesn't work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using a website to do a love calculator module for a bot. This is my syntax:

```
    url = "https://www.lovecalculator.com/love.php?name1={}&name2={}".format(name1, name2)
    async with aiohttp.get(url) as response:
        soupObject = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "html.parser")
    try:
        description = soupObject.soup.find_all('div').find(class_='result score').get_text()
    except:
        description = 'Dr. Love is busy right now.'
```

How do I properly get the result from the website? I'm unable to do that with my current syntax, I always get the 'Dr. Love is busy right now.' message.
Here's the page source:
http://prntscr.com/e4bnhg

Comment: No-one can know what is going wrong because you have cleverly *hidden* all the error messages that Python might want to show you. *Don't* do that; remove that blank `except`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have some syntax errors.

- `soupObject` doesn't have a `soup` property
- `find_all` returns a `ResultSet`, which should be indexed before `find`

Try to change `soupObject.soup.find_all('div').find(class_='result score').get_text()` into `soupObject.find_all('div')[0].find(class_='result score').get_text()`.

Here is my code which works like a charm:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

name1, name2 = 'Alice', 'Bob'
url = 'https://www.lovecalculator.com/love.php?name1={}&name2={}'.format(name1, name2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), 'html.parser')
love = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'result score'}).get_text().strip()
print(love)
```

The result is 54%

Comment: urllib2 is for Python 2, while I'm using 3.5. I changed it to python 3 code and I got an error: Error in command 'lovecalculator' - UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2122' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)

Tried again, now it works, The error was due to a character in the user's name.

Comment: Sorry to forget your python version, I'm no python 3 expert. But as Daniel Roseman menthoned above, remove the `except` part or print the actual exception message helps debugging.